# How to get RubyMine to choose the correct test

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

In RubyMine (and other JetBrains products like IntelliJ or PyCharm), a common task is to switch between a file containing a class and the corresponding file containing tests for that class, using `shift` `command/ctrl` `T`.

However, my RubyMine installation seems unable to identify the correct test file, even though the test contains a direct reference to the class I have open, and even though the test file is in a `project/spec/` directory symmetrical to the class file in `project/app/` and has the same name as the file with `_spec` appended.

**Example**

File I have open in RubyMine:

```
# in project/app/models/event_source.rb
class EventSource < ApplicationRecord
   # ...
end
```

Test file I would like to switch to:

```
# in project/spec/models/event_source_spec.rb

RSpec.describe EventSource, type: :model do
     # ...
end
```

When I have `event_source.rb` open and use the shortcut to open the test file, RubyMine always presents me with a window titled "Choose Test for *event_source.rb* (7 found)" that offers:

- `spec/helpers/event_sources_helper_spec.rb`
- `spec/views/event_sources/edit.html.erb_spec.rb`
- (other view specs)
- `spec/models/event_sources_spec.rb` (the correct test file)
- `spec/controllers/event_sources_controller_spec.rb`

**How can I configure or fix RubyMine to correctly guess the corresponding test file, rather than showing the wrong test files that happen to contain an element of the same name?**

I assume other JetBrains products offer similar functionality and that users of PyCharm, IntelliJ, or PHPStorm might know a solution.

Comment: In PhpStorm the test file must be located in folder marked as Test Sources and file name must match specific hardcoded pattern (e.g. "SomeClass" + "SomeClassTest"). At very least that's for PHPUnit. Each language will have own implementation for such Test <-> Test Subject navigation and may depend on the framework/Test library that you use. I suggest checking related tickets in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17742

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne I'll check out the tickets. Your description matches my assumptions: that there is a specific hardcoded pattern for matching tests. Have you encountered documentation of that pattern or any means of configuring it?

Comment: 1) I'm not RubyMine user 2) What's your IDE version? Try latest 2019.3 if you are using older one. 3) Check other tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY?q=test%20navigation. For example: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16922, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13581, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14262, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13714, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9111 etc